# Python format not working as I would expect

Tags: python

```
 shutil.move(self.filepath+'//'+self.filename, self.archive+'//' + '_{}_' +self.filename.format(today))
```

The file format is not like I would expect. _{}_filename.csv
I need to have the file look like _20201104_filename.csv

Any help would be great, thank you in advance

Comment: You're only formatting `self.filename`, not `self.archive+'//' + '_{}_' +self.filename`.

Comment: Thank you! I just need to wrap it: shutil.move((self.filepath+'//'+self.filename), (self.archive+'//' + '_{}_' + self.filename).format(today))

Answer (score 1):

Why not format the whole string? (Yours only formatting the last attribute)

```
shutil.move('{}/{}'.format(self.filepath,self.filename),'{}/{}/_{}_'.format(self.archive,self.filename,today))
```

Comment: Note that OP is passing *two* arguments to `move`, not just one.

Comment: *You've* combined OP's two arguments into one incorrectly…! Yes, they can probably figure it out, but, ya know…

Comment: Good idea, I need to have the first argument for shutil.move so I did: shutil.move('{}/{}', '{}/{}/{}/{}/_{}_'.format(self.filepath, self.filename, self.archive, self.filename, today)) but im getting the error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '{}/{}'